# Determining if a stochastic process is a markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

> Let $\{X_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ be two-state Markov Chain with state space $S=\{0,1\}$, transition matrix
>   $$ P=
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     1-p       & p \\
>     q & 1-q
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   and initial distribution $\pi _0 = (\pi _0 (0),\pi_0 (1))$. Introduce new stochastic process $\{Y_t\}_{t\geq 1}$ and $\{Z_t\}_{t\geq 1}$ by setting $Y_t=X_t+X_{t-1}$ and $Z_t=10X_t+X_{t-1}$.
>
> Are either of $\{Y_t\}_{t\geq 1}$ or $\{Z_t\}_{t\geq 1}$ Markov Chains ?

My attempt:

$\{Y_t\}_{t\geq 1}$ is not a Markov Chain as
$$\mathbb{P}(Y_3=0|Y_{2}=1,Y_1=1)\neq \mathbb{P}(Y_2=0|Y_2=1,Y_1=0) $$
Was not able to find a counterexample for $\{Z_t\}_{t\geq 1}$

---

Looking for :

1) An intuitive reasoning as to why $\{Y_t\}_{t\geq 1}$ is not a Markov Chain.

2) Whether or not $\{Z_t\}_{t\geq 1}$ is a Markov Chain and an intuitive reasoning for it.

3) Your thought process in determining whether or not a stochastic process is a Markov Chain.

Any insight is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: 1. Y is not a Markov chain because knowing only the current Y hides the current X, on which the distribution of the next Y also depends. 2. Knowing Z is knowing X hence Z is Markov.

Comment: Why should $Z $ be Markov?

Comment: @Ian Since the state space equals $\{0,1\}$, we have $$Z_t = Z_t \mod 2 = X_{t-1},$$ i.e. $(Z_t)_{t}$ is simply the shifted Markov chain $(X_t)_t$

Comment: @saz While I agree with you under that interpretation of the problem statement, I don't think that's the intended interpretation. I think $\{ 0,1 \}$ is the state space of $X_t$ but the state space of $Z_t$ is $\{ 0,1,10,11 \}$ (i.e. $\{ 10x+y : x,y \in \{ 0,1 \} \}$).

Comment: @Ian But also with this interpretation, it is not difficult to see that $Z$ is Markov'sch. Basically, $Z_t$ equals $(X_{t-1},X_t)$ since we can extract both $X_t$ and $X_{t-1}$ from $Z_t$. This means in particular that $$Z_{t+1} = 10 X_{t+1}+X_{t} "=" (X_{t+1},X_t)$$ (=the future) conditioned on $Z_t "=" (X_{t-1},X_t)$ (=the present) equals the conditional expectation with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t^Z$.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. That's pretty neat. (Basically, $Z_t$ contains $X_t,X_{t-1}$ as its digits.)